# parser php ошибка find()

Tags: php, curl, find

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
require_once 'curl_query.php';
$site = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=OUTCODE%5E1558&radius=0.25&propertyTypes=detached%2Csemi-detached%2Cterraced&primaryDisplayPropertyType=houses&maxDaysSinceAdded=7';
$html = curl_get($site);
$dom = str_get_html($html);
$a_links = $dom -> find('a');
echo $a_links;
echo $dom;
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean

p.s. print_r $dom  показал что он пустой (хотя с другими сайтами все норм)

На всякий случай листинг curl_query.php:

```
function curl_get($url, $referer = 'http://www.google.com')
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozila/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) 
    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;

}
```

Comment: А в `$html` что нибудь есть?

Comment: ссылка какая та системная. Попробуйте просто https://www.rightmove.co.uk

Comment: 1) $html заполняется нормально 
2) нужено парсить именно с поиска, но в любом случае find() выбивает ошибку и на простом google.com